# How to use awk to edit lines in a file

Tags: variables, awk, append, printf

I have a file that has a bunch of unique entries in it, each one on its own line.  I'm trying to take some system variables I've created and insert them into the file on the respective line.  I keep getting it inserted on the next line, or a random carriage return.

Here is an example of the file:

```
[default]
access_key =
bucket_location = US
cloudfront_host = cloudfront.amazonaws.com
```

Here is the script / commands I've figured out so far:

```
accesskey="ACCESSKEYWOULDENDUPHERE"
awk -i inplace -v x="$accesskey" '{print} /access_key =/ {print x}' /root/.s3cfg
```

This is what happens

```
[default]
access_key =
ACCESSKEYWOULDENDUPHERE
bucket_location = US
cloudfront_host = cloudfront.amazonaws.com
```

As you can see, I end up inserting on a new line.

My goal is for it to look like this:

```
[default]
access_key = ACCESSKEYWOULDENDUPHERE
bucket_location = US
cloudfront_host = cloudfront.amazonaws.com
```

I am trying to figure out how to use printf but its just not working out so far.

Comment: What is your value of `accesskey`? How are you storing it?

Comment: added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the `access_key` value all you need to do is set the delimiter as `=` and match the field in `$1` to contain `access_key` (remember the trailing whitespace) and update the `$2` value accordingly. The reason is for absolute strings (not changing like `access_key`), it would be more easy to do a direct comparison than do a regex match of it.

```
awk -v x="$accesskey" -vFS='=' -vOFS='=' '$1 == "access_key "{$2=" "x}1' file
```

Add the `-i inplace` flag once you find it working as you wanted it.

Comment: That works nicely. I'm really surprised this answer was so hard to google. I found a million examples of how to append lines to the end or beginning, how to insert them in the middle, but no 'search and edit where blah equals' examples

Comment: @CarComp: Happy you found the answer useful. It comes by practice, if you want to use how to use `Awk` more, read  Ed Morton's answers in it. Search under users for the name and look it up